# How to dynamically set a default boostrap tab on page load based on MVC JsonResult

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a set of tabs in my dashboard and I want to enable my users to set their default tab view to load whenever they log in. I'm getting the value back from the DB in MVC by use of an AJAX call to a Json method. I just need to get the JS/razor view side working. Advice on how to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

**Code**

```
 //Load Account Preferences
    function loadAccountPreferences() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '/JsonUserSettings/GetUserSettings',
            success: function (result) {
                loadDefaultTab(result);                    
            },
            error: function(error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
    }

    loadDefaultTab = function (tabId) {

        $("#dashboardTabs a: tabId").tab('show'); 
    }
```

Comment: If anything it should be; `$("#dashboardTabs a: " + tabId).tab('show');` Not sure what kind of selector `a:` is though, it doesn't exist as far as I know. Depending what you store in the DB, make sure you include a # symbol like so `"#dashboardTabs a: #" + tabId` if it's not stored in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with it a bit, I found a working solution! The only thing I would change is to incorporate Adriani6's recommendation of storing the default tab value in the db with a # preceding the tab name. The following works!

```
  //Load Account Preferences
    function loadAccountPreferences() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '/JsonUserSettings/GetUserSettings',
            success: function(result) {
                loadDefaultTab(result);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
    }

    loadDefaultTab = function(tabId) {
        let defaultTab = '#' + tabId;
        $('.nav a[href="#"]').attr("href",defaultTab).tab('show');
    }
```

Comment: It's still wrong. It probably only works because the tab is always last that you show. Your issue is this `$('.nav a[href="#"]').attr("href",defaultTab).tab('show');` What you're doing here is find all elements that are a tags with href that contains # symbol only and are inside elements that contain the nav class then you apply (change) the href value to all elements to be the one fetched from DB and you show it, but you always end up showing the last one. Inspect it with Dev. tools and you'll see what I mean. I assume you still are looking for my selector that I posted in the comments.

Comment: If it's still wrong, can you point to a better solution because according to the documentation for css and jQuery, that's a commonly applied way to dynamically change tabs. The only change would be to have it set that assignment prior to the page load

Answer (score 0):

As I pointed out in my comment, the code you have posted is wrong as it will always show you the last tab, here's the reasoning...

Let's split your code into parts to see what's happening...

`$('.nav a[href="#"]')` - Here you grab all elements (you'll have more than one if...) that are `<a>` and contain href with a value of "#" and are contained inside an element that contains a class `nav`.

Look at this dummy HTML...

```
<div class="nav">
    <a href="#">First</a>
    <a href="#">Second</a>
    <a href="/Settings">Third</a>
    <a href="/Help">Fourth</a>
</div>
```

Your array would contain First and Second elements, and as all operations you do on array apply to each element inside it, you'll be modifying those two.

At this point you have an array of elements (if you have more than one that matches the condition specified above.

Now that we know you have an array, the next function applied the same thing to every element in that array... therefore each tab now gets a href with a value of `defaultTab`.

Lastly, you call `.tab('show')`, being it an array, and your setup probably only allowing one tab to be shown at a time, it'll always show you the last tab.

If you have your href set already and you are not loading them dynamically (which your answer makes them since you apply the same href to them), you should modify and use the selector I posted under your question `$("#dashboardTabs a: " + tabId).tab('show');`

To fit your answer it would look like this

`$('.nav a[href="'+defaultTab+'"]').tab('show');`

This works the same way as above, but now you're matching the href as you probably would want and you're not modifying the value of any element.